# Where are the program icons for Outlook 2013 stored?

Tags: outlook, icons

Can someone please tell me where the program icons for Microsoft Outlook 2013 are stored?  I am referring to the icons used in the actual application, such as those shown below.
[image: Outlook 2013 icons]

I know these icons are stored in DLLs or EXEs somewhere and I know how to extract the icons.  I just need to find the source file(s).  I've used a program that searches all folders and subfolders within a given directory and displays all of the icons that is finds inside of any file.  I have run it on Program Files\Microsoft Office, Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office, and a few other folders.  Although I do see a few of the Outlook icons in the results, those I show above in particular are nowhere to be found.

**UPDATE:**
To clarify, it's not just those 8 or so specific icons that I am looking for.  I can't find ANY of the icons that are actually used in Outlook 2013.  I find several older Outlook icons, maybe 2010 or so versions, but none of the 2013 ones.  So, for example, I can't find these either:
[image]

Basicaly, ANY of the icons **in** Outlook 2013.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no information where and how Outlook icons are stored. They can be stored as a binary data that's deserialized at runtime. Note, you can take a screenshot and then crop the required image there.

You may find the [Office 2010 Add-In: Icons Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21103) add-in helpful.

Comment: I understand that Msft probably hasn't explicitly stated anywhere where icons are.  I'm looking for someone that happens to know this information.  You can find plenty of information about where Office 2010 icons are (which DLLs to extract from, etc.).  Someone out there has to know.  The icons *must* be in DLLs (or EXEs, etc.) somewhere.  I'm looking for the where.  I can let the icon search prog do a search on my root C drive but I prefer not to have to manually look through thousands of icons to find the Outlook 2013 ones.

Answer (score 0):

The process for extracting the files for Office 2003 is nearly identical to Office 2007, have at look at this question:

[How to save ImageMSO icon from Microsoft Office 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073322/how-to-save-imagemso-icon-from-microsoft-office-2007)

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll

Also ... https://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/change-outlook-2013s-icon/

Answer (score -1):

Remove from your taskbar etc

go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14

find [OUTLOOK.EXE]  and send to desktop as shortcut

Open using this shortcut

Drag shortcut to your task bar

Icon will be back